# how re-scale a range of ratio values, to start from 1 rather then 0, without losing statics significance

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I'm working on a forecast formula for subscriptions.

- First broken down subscriptions by week.
- Second Grouped subscriptions by week.
- Third Found the ratio by week.

-

The roadblock that I'm facing is..

- The ratio range goes from `0.56 to 5.54`
- it need to be `ratio => 1`
- So when I multiply the Actual subscriptions by ratio like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ "Weeks" : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] ,
                    "Subscription" : [203,150,120,80,15,13,5,1] })



df["ratio"] = ((df.Subscription_*100) / (df.Subscription_.sum()) )


## So for example:

Actual_value = 100

# if Actual value multiply by number smaller then 1 such **0.56**

# Foretasted value will be smaller then Actual value, but it should be => Equal or Bigger then Actual.
```

#### How normalize this ratio value in such way that is will begins with range `1 to whatever`

without losing the statistic significance ??

Comment: Why do you use `.`/attribute style for column access, instead of `[ ]`?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way for your output

```
(df.Subscription-df.Subscription.min())/np.ptp(df.Subscription)
0    1.000000
1    0.737624
2    0.589109
3    0.391089
4    0.069307
5    0.059406
6    0.019802
7    0.000000
Name: Subscription, dtype: float64
```

Comment: There should not have numbers smaller then 0 ```ratio => 1  ``` so the smaller number should be ```1```  Should not have ```0.589109 and etc..``` Thanks  @YOBEN_S